# OneDrive tray icon disappeared and it's no longer syncing

Tags: windows-7, onedrive

I'm using Windows 7 x64. OneDrive is not syncing. I drag files to the OneDrive folder (it shows up in FileExplorer with a blue cloud icon) but the files do not show up in the web UI when I open it on a different computer.

I no longer have a OneDrive icon in the system tray, so [this troubleshooting page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-OneDrive-sync-problems-83ab0d8a-8400-45b0-8dcf-dc8aa8a6bcf8#OS_Type=Windows) doesn't help since it bases the help on the color of the icon in the system tray.

I wonder if by installing Office 2016 a while ago, my previous OneDrive install got clobbered.

How would I reinstall the OneDrive desktop app for Windows 7 x64 without losing everything that has been copied up to the cloud?

Comment: Check this Microsoft link for more [info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-OneDrive-sync-problems-83ab0d8a-8400-45b0-8dcf-dc8aa8a6bcf8).

Comment: Manually launch the legacy desktop OneDrive and verify your still logged in

Comment: Don't know how it got logged out.